# Nodejs Syntax Error: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js

i had this script in nodejs and it worked fine
it just take with post command a json  with 4 field (an address) and send back longitude and latitude
i tried it today and it doesnt work anymore without change anything

i get an error when i send a curl command like this:

```
curl -d '{"civico":NUMBER,"via":STREET,"citta":CITY,"stato":STATE}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" localhost:8080
```

error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '
at parse (C:\Users\Edoardo\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
at C:\Users\Edoardo\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:116:18
at invokeCallback (C:\Users\Edoardo\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:262:16)
at done (C:\Users\Edoardo\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:251:7)
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\Edoardo\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:307:7)
at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

code:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    var APIKey =  "API";
    var z = "";

    //POST
    app.post("/", function(req, res) {
        var civico = req.body.civico+'+';
        var via = req.body.via.replace(/ /g,'+')+',+'; 
        var citta = req.body.citta.replace(/ /g,'+')+',+';
        var stato = req.body.stato;

        var address = civico+via+citta+stato;
        console.log(address);
        geocode(address,res);
        console.log(z);
    }); 


    function geocode(input,res){
        var str = '';
        var http = require('https');
        var options = {
          host: 'maps.googleapis.com',
          path: '/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+input+'&key='+APIKey
        };

        callback = function(response) {
          response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
            return 
          });

          response.on('end', function () {
            //console.log(str);
            //fare parsing di str e inviare i dati al client

            var obj = JSON.parse(str);
            var lat = obj.results[0].geometry.location.lat
            var lng = obj.results[0].geometry.location.lng
            str = "Posizione:\nLatitudine -> "+lat+"\nLongitudine -> "+lng+"\n"

            res.status(200).send(str);
        });
    }

    http.request(options, callback).end();

    }

    app.listen(8080, console.log('Server listening on port 8080...'));
```

whats the problem?
thanks

Comment: The error is raised by the body-parser, it means that you are not posting valid JSON.

Comment: @MatthieuLemoine what do u mean?

Comment: '{"civico":NUMBER,"via":STREET,"citta":CITY,"stato":STATE}' is not valid JSON

Comment: @MatthieuLemoine i used the same command that worked days ago
anyway what is the problem?

Comment: String must be quoted with double quote ``"``. It's not about your code but your curl command

Comment: ``curl -d '{"civico":0,"via":"STREET","citta":"CITY","stato":"STATE"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" localhost:8080`` should work

Comment: @MatthieuLemoine what i posted was an example for not insert my own address
 the string with capital letter in my example obviously are with quote in my terminal


solved: i had to put double quote out of parentesis
ex: "{\"civico\":\"12\"}"

thanks

Comment: Did you try ? it works. it returns ``Posizione:
Latitudine -> 39.7847873
Longitudine -> -94.74496529999999``

Comment: it worked using double quote before and after parentesis i dont know why

Comment: BTW you should not post your API key